# Is there a way to insert more than one data in a field in SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to insert more than one `course` in a field of per `student_id` under `course_taken` column where each value has separate by a `','`.

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| student_id |         course_taken         |
+-------------------------------------------+
|   133072   | CSE 1101, CSE 1102, CSE 1103 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Is it possible?

Comment: this is not the way you should be using a RDBMS. There are thousands of questions here from people who took this path and are now stuggling

Comment: Normalize your data.  Let each CSV component occupy its own row.

Comment: Why would you like to do this? this is not practical and not recommended... then how will you filter for example, or index, or...

Comment: This is a terrible idea - how would you query, for example, students that have taken `CSE 1102`? You need a `STUDENT` table, a `COURSE` table and a `STUDENT_COURSE` table. This is a standard many-to-many relationship.

Comment: You're getting hounded here because you're ignoring the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule)
of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). That character column contains a *fixed* amount of data, which means you have arbitrary and in this case unpredictable limits on how many courses a student can take.

Comment: @tadman meh, make it a `LONGTEXT` and the limit is so large that it's _essentially_ infinite. Doesn't make it a good idea. Obviously.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Considering the cost of searching these fields goes up depending on their length, that's a crazy bad idea. Also a 2GB field is not really "essentially infinite" considering drives are typically multiple TB these days.

Answer (score 4):

`course_taken` should be an `M:N` relation between `student` and `course`. It is implemented with a separate table in relational databases, not inline data.

Simply put:

```
CREATE TABLE course (
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,
    course_code varchar NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE student (
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,
    full_name varchar NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE course_taken (
    course_id int NOT NULL,
    student_id int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_course_taken
        PRIMARY KEY (course_id, student_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_course_taken_course_id 
        FOREIGN KEY (course_id)
        REFERENCES course (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_course_taken_student_id 
        FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
        REFERENCES student (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

To answer your question, yes, you can store such data inline in some text field. But you really should not.

Comment: Might be worth giving a quick example of table structure. +1 either way (not least because of the awesome first name)

Comment: Sage advice from one Boris to another :-)